# How to make 2 sections take same space

Tags: html, css

How to make 2 sections take same space like in this reference picture without filling it with 
`<br>` or invisible signs.[image: reference]

```css
body{
    background: #CCFFCC;
}

.container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
.banner{
    background-color: #66CC99;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 8%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
.table-block{
    height: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #66CC99;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    filter: sepia(60%);
}
table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
tr{
    width: 100%;
}

.left, .right{
    background-color: #CBDDE7;
    width: 48%;
    height: 55%;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 1%;
    border: solid 2px #818181;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.right{
    float: right;
    line-height: 1,8em;
}
.left{
   float: left;
}
h3{
    color: #66CC99;
    text-indent: 3%;
}
.left p{
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    color: black;
}
ul{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Świat storczyków </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="banner">
            <p>Świat storczyków</p>
        </section>
        <section class="table-block">
            <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                <img src="https://zielonyogrodek.pl/i/images/2/8/3/d2FjPTkwMHgxLjQwMA==_src_76283-pomaraczowo-rowy-storczyk.jpg">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/pressland-cms/cache/__original__/x3/16999438-falenopsis-mozna-kupic-nawet-w-hipermarkecie-slynie.jpeg">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://ogrodniktomek.pl/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/DSCN6024-1.jpg">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="https://bros.pl/sites/default/files/orchid-748534_1920.jpg">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/darmowe-zdjecie/biale-i-fioletowe-storczyki-dendrobium_24411-34.jpg">
                </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
        </section>
        <section class="left">
            <p>
               Storczyki to rośliny mające jedne z najpiękniejszych i najciekawszych kwiatów na Ziemi.
               Nazywane są również orchideami.
            </p>
            <p>
                Najpiękniejsze storczyki pochodzą z południowo-wschodniej
                Azji, gdzie rosną od Himalajów po Archipelag Malajski, oraz z tropikalnych
                obszarow Ameryki Środkowej i Ameryki Południowej.
            </p>
            <p>
                Storczyki należą do największej rodziny roślin kwitnących. Gatunków orchidei jest na 
                swiecie w tej chwili ponad 30 tysięcy, a ich liczba stale się zwiększa.
            </p>
            <p>
                Orchidea to kwiat niezwykłe delikatny. Podarowany w prezencie, wskazuje na szacunek 
                i podziw dla obdarowanej nim osoby. Jest pięknym podarunkiem na każdą okazję.
            </p>
            <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
        </section>
        <section class="right">
            <h3 class="indent">
                Gatunki orchidei
            </h3>
            <ul>
                <li>storyczyk blady (Orchis pallens L.)</li>
                <li>storczyk błotny (Orchis palustris Jacq.)</li>
                <li>storczyk cuchnący (Orchis cariophora L.)</li>
                <li>storczyk drobnokwiatowy (Orchis ustulata L.)</li>
                <li>storczyk kukawka (Orchis militaris L.)</li>
                <li>storczyk męski (Orchis mascula (L.) L.)</li>
                <li>storczyk purpurowy (Orchis purpurea Huds.)</li>
                <li>storczyk samczy (Orchis morio L.)</li>
                <li>storczyk trójzębny (Orchis tridentata Scop.)</li>
            </ul>
            <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try flex-box https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 div with class "flex" above 2 section left & right .flex{display:flex}

.item { flex: 1 1 0; width: 0; }

Comment: Please use formatting in your answers, otherwise it looks bland and doesn't look like an answer.

Comment: Needs code formatting and more explanation